# The >>= implementation of (State s) Monad in Haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, state

In the book "Learn You A Haskell for Great Good", The implementation of >>= operator in (State s) Monad is:

```
instance Monad (State s) where 
    return x = State $ \s -> (x, s) 
    (State h) >>= f = State $ \s -> let (a, newState) = h s 
                                        (State g) = f a
                                    in g newState
```

As we know, the >>= operator has the type `>>=::m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b`. The second parameter of this operator is a function *f* whose type is `(a -> m b)`, so why the type of input of function *f* in the implementation of (State s) is not `s -> (a, s)` but just the result `a`?

---

**Thanks for everybody! I think I have figured out how >> = works.** We cannot treat the input type of function *f* as the type contained in Monad, but we should consider it as the input type of monad.

Comment: The type `a -> m b` literally means "a function with input `a` and output `m b`". That's why its input is `a`

Comment: The author was helpful here in giving the variables names that match their types. The first function, gives an `a` and a `s` (newState), and the second function (`f`) takes that `a` and makes it into a `m b`.

Answer (score 3):

Since `f` has type `a -> m b` (actually, `a -> State s b`), its input has type `a`. It is the *output* whose type has the shape `s -> (b, s)` (actually, `State s b`) you mention.